# Javascript dropdown menu value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to access the value of a selected option in a drop down menu. I continuously am left with an "undefined" value.

Here is the HTML list I created:

```js
function setDifficulty() {
  var difficultySelector = document.getElementById("difficulty");
  var difficulty = difficultySelector.selectedIndex;

  if (difficulty.options[difficulty.selectedIndex].value == "0") {
    window.alert("easy");
  } else if (difficulty.options[difficulty.selectedIndex].value == "1") {
    window.alert("medium")
  } else if (difficulty.options[difficulty.selectedIndex].value == "2") {
    window.alert("hard");
  } else
    window.alert(difficulty.value);
}
```

```html
<select id="difficulty" onchange="setDifficulty();">
  <option value="0">Easy</option>
  <option value="1">Medium</option>
  <option value="2">Hard</option>
</select>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: difficulty is already give you index hence you dont use again difficulty.selectedIndex

Comment: Most browsers support `document.getElementById("difficulty").value` - it does help if you have a “please select” to allow the onchange to trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will work

```
function setDifficulty() {
    var difficultyElt = document.getElementById("difficulty");
    var value = difficultyElt.options[difficultyElt.selectedIndex].value;
    if (value == "0") {
      window.alert("easy");
    } else if (value == "1") {
      window.alert("medium")
    } else if (value == "2"){
      window.alert("hard");
    }   
}
```

Also, you may output your text value directly:

```
var difficultyElt = document.getElementById("difficulty");
var text = difficultySelector.options[difficultySelector.selectedIndex].text;
window.alert(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get a value from input. You don't need these tricky calculations of value. Also, when you want to work with specific values it's better to use switch-case. It seems much cleaner and needs less code.

```js
function setDifficulty() {
    var difficultySelector = document.getElementById("difficulty");
    var difficulty = difficultySelector.value;
    
    switch (difficulty) {
      case "0":
        window.alert("easy");
        break;
      case "1":
        window.alert("medium");
        break;
      case "2":
        window.alert("hard");
        break;
      default:
        window.alert(difficulty.value);
    }
 }
```

```html
<select id="difficulty" onchange="setDifficulty();">
               <option value="0">Easy</option>
               <option value="1">Medium</option>
               <option value="2">Hard</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Except the onchange is not triggered on the first selection

Comment: @mplungjan please, explain yourself. I cannot understand your idea. Also, as I understood, the problem was about getting value.

Comment: You can not trigger onchange on a value that cannot be changed to. To get value easy now, you first have to change to another option. You need a “please select” and a test for empty

Comment: Anyway, it's not hard if you can get the value. If it's empty just do nothing, or warn. Also it can be done by disabling button until option is chosen

Comment: So just add an introducing option with `hidden` attribute which will make that option unable to be chosen.